# Передача данных разным страницам ajax

Tags: ajax

Доброго всем времени суток

```
// в коде сайта ссылки
<a style=\"{cursor:pointer}\" id=\"123\">Link1</a>
<a style=\"{cursor:pointer}\" id=\"312\">Link3</a>
<a style=\"{cursor:pointer}\" id=\"234\">Link4</a>
<a style=\"{cursor:pointer}\" id=\"422\">Link6</a>

// которые post'ом передают данные
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id != 'goTop'){
        $.ajax({
        url: "page.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(text) {
        $("#text").html(text);
        }
    });
    }
});
});
</script>

// ест-но страница page.php - принимает данные, переваривает, и если нужно, то выводит результат в блок div на странице <div id=\"text\"></div>
```

Охота одними ссылками передавать данные одной странице,
другими ссылками другой странице.

id при этом примерно одинаковые, так что логической проверки не сделать. Подскажите как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a id="123" class="first" href="javascript:doLoad(this);">Link1</a>
<a id="312" class="two" href="javascript:doLoad(this);">Link2</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

function doLoad(element) {
var url = '';
   if ($(element).hasClass("first"))
       url = 'a.php';
  else
       url = 'b.php';

var id = $(element).attr('id');
if(id != 'goTop'){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#text").html(data);
        }
    });
} 
}

</script>
```