# Перетаскивание div'ов на определенную таблицу с сохранением позиции

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, php

Доброго всем времени суток господа.

Представьте себе рабочий стол, на котором значки выровнены не по сетке, и не автоматически, а в разнобой, криво, как это обычно любят девушки делать (про всех не говорю). Если есть котенок на рабочем столе, значит обязательно значки обтекают этого котенка )

Теперь представьте web страница, на ней есть таблица, внутри нее несколько `div`'ов (`~200х250px`, `id` у них `p1010`, `z200`). Ниже находиться Таблица 2, размер ее всегда разный. Хочется 'взять' `div`'ы (сколько их неизвестно) и поочередно перетащить их на таблицу 2. А если там уже есть `div`'ы то возможность изменить им положение, если нужно. В итоге получаться 'хаотично' расположенные на странице `div`'ы. И тут, их расположение мне охота сохранить (сразу вспоминается ajax, но из ajax знаю только [простое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/161801/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC-ajax)). Запомнить положение ест-но для того, что бы эту таблицу 2, с текущими на ней div'ами править потом

Может ли кто привести пример, кода, как хоть примерно это делается?

p.s. Во многих случаях решения, которые есть на хэшкоде в простом виде дорабатываются и не хуже того, что можно готовое найти гуглем, что нужно сначала урезать, если повезет, а потом добавлять. Вот и хочется какую то конструкцию, простую, что бы можно было вникнуть и настроить на свой лад.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делал что-то подобное на своём проекте. Использовал `jquery ui sortable (connect list)`. При окончании переноса запускался таймер, который через определенный промежуток времени отсылал ajax запрос, либо выключался при переносе след. объекта. За сохранение позиций отвечала sqlite, в которую записывались значения объектов. При открытии страницы из БД происходил выбор этих объектов на свои позиции.

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/5QgYP/

Comment: Сам копал в эту сторону, пытался разбираться в примерах, пока к сожалению безрезультатно

Comment: На чем застопорились? У вас элементы перетаскиваются? Если нет - то делайте, инструкций в интернете много. Как получить коллекцию тегов, как их отправить и обработать - уже подскажу.

Comment: Застопорилось вот на чем. Везде нахожу так называемые списки, на которых написаны имена, и их можно перетаскивать относительно друг друга вверх вниз. Вот собственно.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5QgYP/ посмотрите. В console.log выводится сформированный массив элементов.

Comment: вот наверное то что вам надо [jQuery-Droppable][1], а [здесь][2] есть описание на русском



  [2]: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B

  [1]: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#propagation

Comment: @lampa - вот примерно о таких списках я и написал, правда приведенный пример гораздо лучше уже имеющихся у меня. @archi_sova - это для меня шаг вперед. вот только аджаксом координаты дива нужно передать